# wxpython: wait for events mainloop freezes

Tags: multithreading, wxpython

I am new to wxPython, so please be gentle. I am trying to make a game using wxPython. I need to be able to handle events (button clicks) while the game is in progress.

The process is:

1. Deal the cards
2. Wait for user input
3. Continue accordingly

The way I have implemented it is:

```
app = wx.App()
g = Game() # calls g.Play() which executes the process above
app.Mainloop()
```

However the application freezes. I think the problem relates to being unable to respond to events while the process is being executed. How can I get around this?

I had a look at threading, but cannot see how to make this work in my case. If I create a new thread to deal with user inputs from within Game(), that will not be able to update the values in Game().

I am sure there is a "correct" way of doing this which I don't know because I am unfamiliar with wxPython. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo do not need a seperate function `play()` to run the game. Just set up the event handlers to compute the state of the game during every event which results in a move of the game.

A good option would be to define a game state as say the cards in each players hands, and  the turns that have been played and the scores, all defined as an object of a state `class`.

Chalk out an outline of how your game's architecture first. And you might also want to take a look at some examples and documentations on wxPython if you are new  to it.

Answer (score 0):

wxPython (and all GUI toolkits) are event driven. What this means is that they all wait for the user to "do something", like press a button, move the mouse, press a key on the keyboard, etc. When the uses does one of these things, wxPython checks to see if any of those events are bound to an event handler. If they aren't, wx will usually ignore the events.

You can learn about how to bind events properly here:

- http://wiki.wxpython.org/self.Bind%20vs.%20self.button.Bind

So when you start the program, it should probably deal the cards at the start or possibly prompt the user to see if they want to start a new game or possibly continue a game. After that, the application would wait for the user to "do something". If the user executes a process that takes a long period of time (like a complex calculation, downloading a large file, etc), that process should be put into a thread. If you don't put it into a thread, then that process will block the UI's main loop and your app will freeze. See the following articles for information about wxPython and threads:

- http://wiki.wxpython.org/LongRunningTasks
- http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/05/22/wxpython-and-threads/

I hope these links help you on your way.